# Computing the index in a structured way

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatory-logic

I want to map the various combinations to an unique index:
 For a given $n$ and $r$, we would have $\binom{n}{r}$ arrangement for values:$[0,\dots,n)$:

Ex: For n = 6, r = 3
[012,
013,
014,
015,
...,
345]
So, for any given arrangement [012] the index would 0 as its the very first element.
Similarly, the index for arrangement for [015] should be 3. Trying to come up a formula to determine the correct index for a given arrangement.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system, http://stackoverflow.com/q/127704/781723

Comment: @D.W. Now the question has become unanswerable. Why not convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, I don't understand why the question has become unanswerable.  I don't have time right now to write up a full answer, but anyone else who would like to is welcome to do so.